# PyQt: How to Generate a Raster Image with a Custom Message

Tags: python, pyqt, qtgui, qtcore

To generate a solid gray image I'm using:

```
def generate_image(filepath):
    img = QtGui.QImage(720, 405, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    img.fill(QtCore.Qt.gray)
    img.save(filepath, 'JPG')
```

I wonder how difficult it would be to customize this function to layer a simple text message on top of the gray background. I appreciate an input!

Comment: Sputnix keep up the good work. I notice that you have a lot of questions that have valid useful answers that you have neither accepted nor upvoted. On SO this is how you thank people (and by answering others questions of course but I understand not everyone is comfortable with that). It is also important to accept answer when it answered your question to close question.

Comment: Sure! I am totally fine thanking everyone for any help or even for taking a participation in a discussion! Thanks everyone!! :) I am just forgetting sometimes to update older posts... Sorry

Comment: It is one of the (several) reasons that SO works so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) to draw on the image:

```
def generate_image(filepath, text='Hello World!', color='red', font=None):
    img = QtGui.QImage(720, 405, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    img.fill(QtCore.Qt.gray)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(img)
    painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(color))
    if font is None:
        font = painter.font()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setPointSize(24)
    painter.setFont(font)
    painter.drawText(img.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, text)
    painter.end()
    return img.save(filepath, 'JPG')
```

Comment: Thanks Ekhumoro! I will give it a try as soon as I get back to this subject in a day or two!

Comment: the code generates the image, but gives an Error:   QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Comment: @Sputnix. It's harmless - just add `painter.end()` to the end of the function.

Comment: Excellent tweak! With painter.end() it runs just perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: I would add this line before img.save(filepath, 'JPG').... since if folder doesnt exist img.save() will save nothing and yet it would give no error message: if not os.path.exists( os.path.dirname( filepath ) ): os.makedirs( os.path.dirname( filepath ) )

Comment: @Sputnix. It should be up to the caller to ensure that `filepath` exists. `QImage.save` returns `False` if it doesn't succeed, so it would be better to either return that result or raise an error.

Comment: It is this type of situation where I'm often (as it turns to be later) making a mistake. I have to be really careful in order to avoid it. I wish it would be clear from beginning when exactly it is "up to the caller to ensure or to do". I would appreciate if you point me to a resource where I could read more on how to manage a program 'flow' in this regard... if a such resource exists

Comment: @Sputnix. SO is not really the place to ask for such things, but the [Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules) has some good general advice. I would say that the reason why it should be "up to the caller" is mainly because of modularity. A function that generates an image should not be manipulating the filesystem. Ideally, the function in my answer would just return the image object rather than attempting to save it as well (but it's just example code, so let's not be _too_ fussy).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It is often tempting to include a functionality inside of method or function outside of initially  intended purpose.